Error while sending email from SES through java code
I'm trying to send an email with SES V2 AMAZON , but it fails with the below error
I am getting below error where it's not providing me the proper exception details.
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:125)
how can I solve it:
using this code:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/java_sesv2_code_examples.html
I tried email identity and email arn identity to send email but no use.
using this code:
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.Body;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.Content;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.Destination;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.EmailContent;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.Message;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.SendEmailRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.SesV2Client;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class EmailNotificationUtils {

     public Boolean sendSESEmailNotification(String sender, String recipient, String subject) {

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_2;
        SesV2Client sesv2Client = SesV2Client.builder().region(region).build();

        // The HTML body of the email.
        String bodyHTML = "<html>" + "<head></head>" + "<body>" + "<h1>Hello!</h1>" + "<p>                               This is test eamil.</p>"
                + "</body>" + "</html>";

        send(sesv2Client, sender, recipient, subject, bodyHTML);
        return true;
    }

    public static void send(SesV2Client client, String sender, String recipient, String    subject, String bodyHTML) {

        Destination destination = Destination.builder().toAddresses(recipient).build();

        Content content = Content.builder().data(bodyHTML).build();

        Content sub = Content.builder().data(subject).build();

        Body body = Body.builder().html(content).build();

        Message msg = Message.builder().subject(sub).body(body).build();

        EmailContent emailContent = EmailContent.builder().simple(msg).build();

        log.info("sender {}", sender);
        log.info("destination {}", destination);
        log.info("emailContent {}", emailContent);

         SendEmailRequest emailRequest =      SendEmailRequest.builder().destination(destination).content(emailContent)
                .fromEmailAddress(sender).build();

        try {
            log.info("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES \" + \"using the AWS SDK for Java.. {}",
                    emailRequest.fromEmailAddressIdentityArn());
            client.sendEmail(emailRequest);
            log.info("email was sent");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception occured while sending message with exception {}", e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}

Dependencies:
<dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
   <version>2.17.288</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>sesv2</artifactId>
   <version>2.17.288</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
   <version>2.17.288</version>
</dependency>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community , I have added the code and dependencies used.
